# How to pass a json response to a function: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm trying to use data from an api to use it in a function:

```js
// Fetch JSON from an external endpoint
    d3.json('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5eee6a5397cb753b4d149343').then(data => this.drawBars(data));
    
    private drawBars(data: any[]): void { ... }
```

But I get this error and can't figure out how to solve it:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Any guidance is appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
    d3.json('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5eee6a5397cb753b4d149343')
       .then(data => this.drawBars(data as any[]));
```

or if you want to be sure it's an array and avoid 'as' keyword:

```
    d3.json('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5eee6a5397cb753b4d149343')
       .then(data => {
           if(Array.isArray(data) {   
               this.drawBars(data)
           } else {
           // throw error or other logic
           }
       );
```

Comment: Thank you @t-MURO the 'as' did the job. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: @Probandot I would recommend using the second solution I posted. It's safer :)

Answer (score 0):

> It's because the derived type of data is `unknown` and you are trying
> to assign it to an input of array type.

Try the following

`private drawBars(data: any): void { ... }`